# Change media attachment author via mysql query

Tags: query, author, media

How does one bulk change the media attachment author via an sql query?

I have hundreds of media attachments that need to be moved to another author so the original author can be deleted; but that author has no posts, only media attachments.

(The images were attributed to the author when importing and running a query to take the first post image and make it a featured image.)

I think I need to specify the `post_type' in a query, like this:

`update wp_posts and post_type = ‘attachment’`

**Update:**

As answered below, this works
`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = [NEW_ID] WHERE post_author = [OLD_ID]`

with or without the `AND post_type = 'attachment'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = [NEW_ID] WHERE post_author = [OLD_ID]
```

Comment: I don't need the change the post author; the post doesn't exist. I need to change the author of the media attachment.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: @songdogtech This will also work for media attachments, which are simply post objects in the database.

Comment: @toscho How!? Doesn't get much simpler!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Explain that `post_author` is also an author of attachments. I found your post in our Low Quality queue; and such short posts are usually targets of spam edit suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, with ot without `and post_type = 'attachment'`